# UICollectionview insertItemsAtIndexPaths stops scrolling

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview

I have an infinite loading collectionview – adding new items with: `insertItemsAtIndexPaths`

But every time I call `insertItemsAtIndexPaths` the scrolling stops
`insertItemsAtIndexPaths` runs on the mainthread as it has to

Is there any way I can prevent `insertItemsAtIndexPaths` from stopping the scroll?
(I mean the fast scroll)

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so i answer my own question :)

moved the code that triggers the `insertItemsAtIndexPath` from `scrollViewDidScroll` to `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` - solves the issue :)

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for your question and answer Helmut, this seemed so obscure that I felt like there was another issue at play. I couldn't find any posts apart from this one so I began thinking what else effected scrolling and found that I would call

```
refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
```

when I get my new data, which although the refresh control wasn't currently refreshing it would still interrupt the scroll. 
Simply changing it to the below fixed the issue.

```
if let refreshing = refreshControl?.isRefreshing, refreshing {
    refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
}
```

Comment: This ended my fruitless search for the reason behind my suboptimal scrolling performance. For hard to explain reasons I was calling endRefreshing() in every call to cellForItemAt().  
  
Updated for newer versions of Swift (5.1)  
  
`
if let refreshing = refreshControl?.isRefreshing, refreshing {  
    refreshControl?.endRefreshing()  
}
`